# How to create object from an xml

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

How do you create an object by `XElement`? I can create a list, but I want a single object and not a list.

Here is my code:

```
XElement elem = XElement.Load(path);
var myList = from n in elem.Descendants("NodeNumber1")
             select new
             {
                 Name = n.Attribute("Name").Value,
                 MyObj = from o in n.Descendants("NodeChild")
                         select new
                         {
                             var1 = o.Descendants("var1").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                             var2 = o.Descendants("var2").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                         }
             };
```

`NodeChild` is in `NodeNumber1` once, so I want it as an object and not as a list. Even `var1` and `var2` are defined once in `NodeChild` - but they are not problematic because I use `FirstOrDefault`).

How I will create it as a single object and not as a list?

Comment: Well you've got two "levels" of output here - one with Name/MyObj, and one with var1/var2. Which do you want to make singular? (Sample XML and expected output would be useful.)

Comment: I get the name - is already singular, and MyObj as a list which has the Var1/Var2, I want this list will become a single object.

Comment: So you want `myList` to still be a list? Can you see how your question is confusing, and could have been much more clearly described, with sample XML and expected output? Please bear this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var axe = elem.Descendants("NodeNumber1")
               .Select(n => new
               {
                   Name= n.Attribute("Name").Value,
                   MyObj= from o in n.Descendants("NodeChild")
                          select new
                          {
                              var1= o.Descendants("var1").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                              var2= o.Descendants("var2").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                          }
               })
               .First();
```

Or using existing query:

```
var axe = axesList.First();
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I edited your answer because I wanted that inner list will be single object and not the external list